# Best practice to release memory after url fetch on appengine (python)

Tags: python, google-app-engine

my problem is how to best release memory the response of an asynchrones url fetch needs on appengine. Here is what I basically do in python:

```
rpcs = []

for event in event_list:
    url = 'http://someurl.com'
    rpc = urlfetch.create_rpc()
    rpc.callback = create_callback(rpc)
    urlfetch.make_fetch_call(rpc, url)
    rpcs.append(rpc)

for rpc in rpcs:
    rpc.wait()
```

In my test scenario it does that for 1500 request. But I need an architecture to handle even much more within a short amount of time.

Then there is a callback function, which adds a task to a queue to process the results:

```
def event_callback(rpc):
    result = rpc.get_result()
    data = json.loads(result.content)
    taskqueue.add(queue_name='name', url='url', params={'data': data})
```

My problem is, that I do so many concurrent RPC calls, that the memory of my instance crashes: **"Exceeded soft private memory limit with 159.234 MB after servicing 975 requests total"**

I already tried three things:

```
del result
del data
```

and

```
result = None
data = None
```

and I ran the garbage collector manually after the callback function.

```
gc.collect()
```

But nothing seem to release the memory directly after a callback functions has added the task to a queue - and therefore the instance crashes. Is there any other way to do it?

Comment: while not a solution as such, changing your instance class will increase the available memory.

Comment: yeah sure - but in terms of cost efficiency that not yet the final solution for me :)

Answer (score 2):

Wrong approach: Put these urls into a (put)-queue, increase its rate to the desired value (defaut: 5/sec), and let each task handle one url-fetch (or a group hereof). Please note that theres a safety limit of 3000 url-fetch-api-calls / minute (and one url-fetch might use more than one api-call)

Comment: problem with tasks is, that due to the latency until response you will need a lot of instances to execute enough tasks in parallel fast enough, which will cost a lot of intance hours. hmm - how can there be a 3000 url-fetch-api-calls / minute limit, when the quota shows me, that I can do 46,342,179 calls? 3000 a minute would mean 4,320,000 calls a day

Comment: There are different limits for free/payed apps. This one was for free apps. See https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/quotas.

As said, you could put a bunch of urls into one task (10, 100, ..) and process them at once. Also, if your application uses threads, one instance could process more than one task at a time. If its hit the memory limit then, it should just abort the recent request(s) (and reschedule these, so nothing would be lost)

Answer (score 1):

Use the task queue for urlfetch as well, fan out and avoid exhausting memory, register named tasks and provide the event_list cursor to next task. You might want to fetch+process in such a scenario instead of registering new task for every process, especially if process also includes datastore writes.

I also find ndb to make these async solutions more elegant.

Check out Brett Slatkins talk on [scalable apps](http://www.google.com/events/io/2009/sessions/BuildingScalableComplexApps.html) and perhaps [pipelines](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zSDC_TU7rtc).

Comment: I don't really understand what you exactly mean by "register named tasks and provide the event_list cursor to next task" - I know how to register a named task, but then do what exactly?

Comment: I just watched the pipelines video. everything explained in the first 15 minutes. thanks a lot! that is the solution to my problem!

Comment: For those who haven't watched the video, named tasks are used to avoid fork bombs, where you would otherwise register duplicate tasks on rerun after failure when your task registers new task and so on.